# Bootstrap - Put image inside <li> in the navbar

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, listitem

The image logo needs to go in the empty list item slot in the top left, beside the Work list item slot

[image]

This is what I have now...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active">
            <a class="brand" href="index.php"><div style="width: 130px; height: 20px; background: url('/images/rsz_logo.jpg') no-repeat left center;"><img src="/images/logo.png"></div></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="services.php">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason it has to be in a list item? if not try the following.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="services.php">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
     <a class="pull-left" href="index.php"><img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Home"></a>
```